# Using accessors in C# stack overflow

Tags: c#, accessor

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786(v=vs.71).aspx

> public string Name  {    get     { 
>         return name;     }    set     {
>         name = value;     } }

So why is it that when I set the value as so:

```
public int numHighAttacksHit
        {
            get { return numHighAttacksHit - handicapHighAttacks; }
            set { numHighAttacksHit = value; }
        }

this.numHighAttacksHit = 0;
```

It keeps circling around again and again setting value to numHighAttacksHit until I reach a stack overflow? This is within the same class, does that matter?

screenshot: http://gyazo.com/a49757753acfbb5b51aaef5be033c948.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property needs a field to reference, like this:

```
private int numHighAttacksHit;
public int NumHighAttacksHit   // <-- note the pascal case
    {
        get { return numHighAttacksHit - handicapHighAttacks; }
        set { numHighAttacksHit = value; }
    }

this.NumHighAttacksHit = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing the property inside of it's definition causing the stack overflow, unlike the example from MSDN.

try

```
private int numHighAttacksHit;
public int NumHighAttacksHit
{
            get { return numHighAttacksHit - handicapHighAttacks; }
            set { numHighAttacksHit = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

C# is case sensitive: Name and name are two different things, and in the MSDN article it has name defined as a private field:

```
private string name;   // the name field
public string Name   // the Name property
{
   get 
   {
      return name; 
   }
}
```

In your example, you don't have that private field, so numHighAttacksHit is going in a loop accessing itself.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the value of the property `numHighAttacksHit` within the property `numHighAttacksHit` itself--this creates a non-terminating recursion and is the source of your stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the second one, you are setting numHighAttacksHit again and again, and in the first one you are setting the value to name variable not to the property.